# lib curl in c++ disable printing

Tags: c++

i got a small program from  http://curl.haxx.se/ and while i run it always prints the webpage how can i disable the printing function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;

      curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 43):

You need to set up a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to make it not use stdout.

There is an explanation here (under CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION):
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

and here (Under "Handling the Easy libcurl):
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

Basically adding the function:

```
size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
   return size * nmemb;
}
```

and calling

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
```

Should do it.

Comment: The callbacks CANNOT be non-static class member functions. https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

You can still get diagnostic messages. To stop these either change or add the following line:

```
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L); //0 disable messages
```

Comment: Just to clarify: setting `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` does NOT prevent curl from printing the content of the fetched URL onto stdout. You need to define `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to prevent that. `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` will only help prevent other diagnostic messages from being printed.

Comment: CURLOPT_VERBOSE is does not stop printing response.

Comment: CURLOPT_VERBOSE displays verbose information. And by default is already disable, 0.
https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html

Answer (score 1):

To write data into file instead of printing, give a file descriptor as:

```
FILE *wfd = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, wfd);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was using the CURLOPT_NOBODY option in the code, referenced here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTNOBODY

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);

        //USING CURLOPT NOBODY
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Followed this because it seemed easier than the other solution but the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) explicitly says that `For HTTP(S), this makes libcurl do a HEAD request.` which usually changes program behavior a lot.