# How to disable cout for the curlopt_headerfunction, prevent printing on screen

Tags: c++, libcurl, cout, disable

I want to use the Curlopt_headerfunction
This works fine

How can i prevent the function to print on screen?

I have found a solution for the write function,

[lib curl in c++ disable printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572397/lib-curl-in-c-disable-printing)

But it does not work with the header function

```
static size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size,size_t nitems, void *userdata)
{
  // received header is nitems * size long in 'buffer' NOT ZERO TERMINATED
  // 'userdata' is set with CURLOPT_HEADERDATA
  return nitems * size;
}

void RecieveData{
curl = curl_easy_init();
std::string sData;
if (curl){
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, Resource.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L); //0 disable messages
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, false);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, false);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &sData);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
printf("Received data %s\r\n", sData.c_str());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that you want to prevent the response body to get output? Then add something like this:

```
static size_t write_cb(char *d, size_t n, size_t l, void *p)
{
   /* take care of the data here, ignored in this example */
  (void)d;
  (void)p;
  return n*l;
}

/* tell curl to use this callback to deliver ("write") data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
```